# Regex to match a string starting with constatant

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like `com.sap.fw.tr.SYSTEM.GKBN` where `GKBN` is variable while rest part is fixed. I used

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^com.sap.fw.tr.SYSTEM.([a-z]*)$");
```

but when I am calling `Matcher.matches();` it is returning `false`.
Can someone point out the mistake in this regex?

Comment: it can be number also??

Answer (score 2):

You're matching an upper case input and have `[a-z]*` that will match lowercase letters only.

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)^com\\.sap\\.fw\\.tr\\.SYSTEM\\.([a-z]*)$");
```

OR this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^com\\.sap\\.fw\\.tr\\.SYSTEM\\.([a-z]*)$", 
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

`(?i)` is used for ignore case matching

Answer (score 0):

You are matching an upper case input with `[a-z]*` that will match lowercase letters only.

Use this

```
^com\\.sap\\.fw\\.tr\\.SYSTEM\\.([A-Z]*)
```

I have tested this in regexplanet.com. it worked! if you want to make case insensitive. You can use `?i` to ignore case matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
("^com\\.sap\\.fw\\.tr\\.SYSTEM\\.([A-Z]+)$");
```

it use only uppercase letter one or more. And better escape `.` symbol with `\.`

Comment: Won't compile. Use \\

Comment: I think one `\\` symbol is enough, isn't it?

Comment: No, the `\\` symbol has to be escaped as well. Before posting an answer first try it out yourself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the most rigid solution if you want to match a valid Java identifier:

```
inputString.matches("\\Qcom.sap.fw.tr.SYSTEM.\\E\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*");
```

This uses `String.matches(String regex)` instead of going through [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

Break down of the pattern:

```
\Qcom.sap.fw.tr.SYSTEM.\E     # Match literal string "com.sap.fw.tr.SYSTEM."
\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}   # Match 1 - starting character of a Java identifier
\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*   # Match 0 or more - part characters of a Java identifier
```

This pattern makes use of `java.lang.Character` classes feature, where you prepend `java` in front of name of methods in `java.lang.Character` classes.

The regex above checks the character based on the [`Character.isJavaIdentifierStart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart%28int%29) and [`Character.isJavaIdentifierPart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart%28int%29) methods.